# How to control application from WebBrowser Control?

Tags: browser, webbrowser-control

I've googled it, but came out empty. And the worst thing is that I know it is possible.

Anyway, I'm developing an application that uses the `WebBrowser` control to display information regarding an object (like Outlook does with the Rules and Alerts dialog box).

My question is how do I do for the click on a, say, hyperlink in the `WebBrowser` execute some function within the Windows Form?

For instance, say I have a link like [this](http://stackoverflow.com) and when I click it I want the application to display an specific form, like the Outlook does when you click on hyperlinks like `People and Distribution List`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks useful: [How to: Implement Two-Way Communication Between DHTML Code and Client Application Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166.aspx)

Comment: That's what I like about stackoverflow. Ask and shall recieve. :P

Answer (score 8):

ChrisW's answer will work, but there's another way if you're just relying on hyperlinks.

In [Comicster](http://comicster.net), I have links in my WebBrowser control like this:

```
<a href="action:FileNew">New Collection</a>
```

And then in the WebBrowser's [Navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) event, I have some code to check if the user has tried to navigate to an "action:" link, and intercept it:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender,
    WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.Scheme == "action")
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        string actionName = e.Url.LocalPath;
        // do stuff when actionName == "FileNew" etc
    }
}
```

With a little bit of code you can even parse the URL parameters and "pass them through" to your host application's action, so I can do things like:

```
<a href="action:EditIssue?ID=1">Edit this issue</a>
```

... which will open a properties dialog for the issue with ID 1.

Comment: Is this way preferable for any reason?

Comment: I use this method because I have end-users who know basic HTML but don't know javascript, and I let them create their own 'skins". This way they only need to know the action names for their links.